# .NET Core - Nuget Pack of UniTest Project shows warning "The assembly is not inside the 'lib' folder"

Tags: c#, .net-core, nuget, nuget-package

I'm trying to pack a UnitTest project as a Nuget package and I always get the following warning(s) if I build my project:

> The assembly
>   'content\SpecFlow.MSDependencyInjection.SpecFlowPlugin.dll' is not
>   inside the 'lib' folder and hence it won't be added as a reference
>   when the package is installed into a project. Move it into the 'lib'
>   folder if it needs to be referenced.

My csproj file looks like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
    <Version>0.1.0</Version>
    <IsPackable>true</IsPackable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Http" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="16.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="MSTest.TestAdapter" Version="1.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="MSTest.TestFramework" Version="1.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="SpecFlow" Version="3.0.188" />
    <PackageReference Include="SpecFlow.MSDependencyInjection.SpecFlowPlugin" Version="1.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="SpecFlow.MsTest" Version="3.0.188" />
    <PackageReference Include="SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation" Version="3.0.188" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

The error still appears if I copy the files into the lib folder of the Nuget package. I'm at a loss what I need to change for this warning to disappear. To be frank I'm not even sure why it appears in the first place because I have a different project that works fine without this error.

**Update 1:**

After the detailed answer from @zivkan I changed my project structure so it is not a UnitTest project anymore.

[image]

Sadly the errors still appear if my project is a class library...

[image]
*Screenshot with all Nuget-Packages that I need for my project to work*

If I only add my own Nuget-Package that consists of two dependencies (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection and SpecFlow) it still produces this error but the two dependencies in this Nuget-Package don't. To me this seems to be a problem with the Nuget-Packages...

Comment: Your screenshot is still showing warnings for `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.dll`, so something doesn't match with what you said about only having two nuget dependencies. Maybe you're still packing the test project and these warnings are from that project, not your new classlib project.

Comment: @zivkan What I meant is that if I delete all Nuget-Packages and only add my Nuget-Package I still get the error. The screenshot is with all Nuget-Packages that I need for my project. I can't remove the TestAdapter because it contains a class that I need. Sorry if that was unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure, but my guess is that since with SDK style csproj files, when you build, only your assembly's dll is normally written to the output directory. When you run a non-test netcoreapp, the dotnet cli looks at what project references and nuget references you have, and configures the assembly loader to load from their "original" locations, rather than having all the assemblies copied to your app's bin folder. Perhaps the unit test framework doesn't support loading assemblies in this way and creates `Content` items out of each dll, which tells the `build` step to copy the content (in this case dlls) into the output directory (`bin\$(Configuration)\$(TargetFramework)`). Therefore, when you run unit tests, the unit test framework has all the required assemblies in the single directory, whereas that's normally not true for non-test projects.

Next you need to understand that when NuGet packs a project, it looks for MSBuild items of the type `Content`, and puts copies of them in the nupkg's `content` and `contentFiles` directories. Due to how NuGet works, only dlls in the `lib\` or `ref\` directories within the nupkg are given to the compiler, therefore any dlls you have a content directory will not be passed to the compiler, so your project that references this nupkg cannot use classes in those dlls. This is not how people usually intend to use NuGet packages and therefore NuGet generates a warning.

So, I believe the reason you're getting this warning is because you're packing a project type that is not intended to be packable. The project type does some uncommon things in order to work, which triggers NuGet warnings because typically when this uncommon thing is done, it's a mistake.

I believe this to be a case of a [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). I assume you're packing a unit test project because you want to share some utility code useful for tests, maybe some mocks or object initialisation code. In this case, I recommend you create a new classlib project, put your shared code in there, leaving all your test cases in your netcoreapp test project, even if it's nothing more than a single method call into the classlib. This way you can pack and share the classlib without warnings. Packing a unit test seems unusual and it would be interesting to discuss why you want to do this, what problem do you intend to solve and if packing a test is really the best way to achieve it. Unfortunately Stack Overflow isn't a good place to have discussions and is often actively discouraged.

Comment: Agree on the XY problem. XUnit has added build tooling to its xunit.core package to make sure people end up with messy packages by default and tell users to use framework or abstraction libraries to write shared test code.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer @zivkan! I updated my answer - I changed my project structure so it is a class library but to no avail... :(

Comment: You were correct it was a XY problem. I restructured my code and removed everything that had to do with the Microsoft UnitTesting Framework. I made it Framework independet and now everything works. (and my own Nuget Package also had a small error in it...)

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you have missed a file, please follow this link for full details : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package#Package_Conventions